# Some code in Android APIDemos Sensors.java puzzle me

Tags: android, sensors

I am reading some codes  about sensor in the Android APIDemos.But some codes puzzle me.

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
    mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mYOffset = h * 0.5f;
    mScale[0] = - (h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.STANDARD_GRAVITY * 2)));
    mScale[1] = - (h * 0.5f * (1.0f / (SensorManager.MAGNETIC_FIELD_EARTH_MAX)));
    mWidth = w;
        mHeight = h;
        if (mWidth < mHeight) {
            mMaxX = w;
        } else {
            mMaxX = w-50;
        }
        mLastX = mMaxX;
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}
```

What's the meaning of mYOffset and mScale?Why they were related to h(size of view)?

Answer (score 0):

mYOffset is the the center of the screen in the y direction

mScale appears to be used for the size of the lines that it draws

And this is a prime example of why you always need to comment your code

Comment: Granted I'm not 100% sure on mScale.  Best way to figure it out is to play around with them and see how the compiled output changes